# Handle sweet alert 2 notifications with Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need to find the text content of a sweet alert, look at the html:

```
<div id="swal2-content" class="swal2-html-container" style="display: block;">Success</div>
```

But even waiting or 'sleeping' i can't find the content!
My code is this:

```js
wd.implicitly_wait(30)
message = wd.find_element_by_id("swal2-content").text
print(message)
if message == 'Success':
  time.sleep(180)
else:
  print(wd.find_element_by_id("swal2-content"))
  break
```

Comment: what was the output of this code ?

Comment: @cruisepandey element is not atached to page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `implicitly_wait` you have to use an `expected conditions` here.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

message  = WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "swal2-content"))).text
```

Because `implicitly_wait` completes immediately when the element is presented on the page, but the element is still not finished rendering in that moment. So element's text is still not there. That's why your expected text `Success` is still not there.

Comment: Thanks but i tried  it and didn't quite work. It gave me a timeout error with no error message! strange.

Comment: What do you mean by no error message? Expected conditions throws timeout exception in case it could not meet the expected condition. Possibly your locator is wrong.